# How to deal with integer(0) vectors being used as indices in a matrix

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame `A` and a vector `b`.

I want to eliminate any columns in `A` with indices that are in `b` by doing `A[,-b]`

Sometimes vector `b` has length 0. In this case I would like the whole of data frame `A` to be returned. Instead I get this error:

> data frame with 0 columns and 1259 rows

How can I make sure this doesn't happen in this case?

Comment: another one `mtcars[if (length(na.omit(b))) b else TRUE, ]`

Comment: where does b come from? if you can express it as a logical vector instead, sunsetting will be robust to the length-0 case (when b is TRUE ncol(A) times)

Comment: @rawr why sort()?

Comment: @MichaelChirico to get rid of NAs. guess na.omit would be better to preserve order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `setdiff()`:

```r
A[, setdiff(1:ncol(A), b)]
```

This method can handle

- `b <- NA`
- `b <- NULL`
- `b <- integer(0)`

and returns the entire data `A`.

Answer (score 1):

Any reason a control statement won't work? Most of the time there's no need to over-complicate things. It also makes it simple for other people who may need to read or edit your code.

```
ret_a = function(A, b) {
    if (length(b) == 0) {
        A
    } else {
        A[,-b]
    }
}
```