# Wanting to remove vector b from matrix A by doing A[-b,] but get an error when b is null

Tags: r, matrix, vector

I have a matrix `A` which I want to remove all rows in vector `b` from by doing `A[-b, ]`.

Sometimes vector `b` can be `NULL` but when I run my code and it is `NULL` I get this error:

```
Error in -NULL : invalid argument to unary operator
```

How can I make sure I don't get this error in this case?

Comment: You could wrap the statement in `if (!is.null(b)) { ... }`

Comment: I think the answers to your previous question accounted for this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to deal with integer(0) vectors being used as indices in a matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72620284/how-to-deal-with-integer0-vectors-being-used-as-indices-in-a-matrix)

Comment: Oh you're right, it does! Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a trick:

```
A[-c(b, nrow(A) + 1), ]
```

I presented this idea in a similar problem back in 2018: [How to safely drop nothing from a vector when the negative index could be integer(0)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52772315/4891738) In this way, we won't worry about `b` being 0, `integer(0)` or NULL, and can use minus index safely.